# Ubuntu 14.04 can not cabal install cpython

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, cabal, ubuntu-14.04, cabal-install

I am trying to install the Haskell package [cpython](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpython) on Ubuntu 14.04, and I get this error message:

```
$ cabal install cpython
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cpython-3.3.0...
cabal: The pkg-config package 'python-3.3' is required but it could not be
found.
Failed to install cpython-3.3.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cpython-3.3.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

My hypothesis is that it requires python3.3-dev or something similar to be installed, but python3.3 seems to have been removed from Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that your hypothesis is correct; you could follow the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-do-i-install-python-3-3) to rectify your problem.

Comment: Yes, it seems to require exactly Python 3.3. However, even after using the deadsnakes PPA on Ubuntu to install Python 3.3, the cabal cpython installation still fails with the same problems.

Comment: You need to install python3.3-dev.  Your hypothesis is correct!